# Django TestCase for group permissions?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing, django-tests

I have a TestCase for some views, but I am also trying to incorporate tests for my `post admin` group. They have permissions to `post.change_post` and `post.delete_post`, just like the user can.

Here is a little code snippet,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from fixtureless.factory import create

from .models import Post


class TestPostViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create(username='test_user')
        self.form = create(Post, {'title': 'test_title'})
        self.client = Client()


    def test_update_post(self):
        """
        Test UpdateView updates users post
        """
        self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.put(reverse('post:update', kwargs={'pk': self.form.pk}),
                                   {'title': 'testing'})
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        # reloads a models value from the database
        self.form.refresh_from_db()
        self.assertEqual(self.form.title, 'test_title')

    def test_delete_confirm_page(self):
        """
        Test DeleteView takes user to confirmation page
        """
        self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.get(reverse('post:delete', kwargs={'pk': self.form.pk}))
        self.assertContains(response, 'delete')

    def test_delete_post(self):
        """
        Test DeleteView deletes a post
        """
        self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('post:delete', kwargs={'pk': self.form.pk}))
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('post:list'))
        self.assertFalse(Post.objects.filter(pk=self.form.pk).exists())
```

Any tips on this? Should I create a separate TestCase for the `post admin`, or is there a way to add this in the initial `setUp()` method?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am getting a little closer with this snippet...

```
class TestPostViews(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        self.user1 = get_user_model().objects.create(username='test_user1')
        self.user2 = get_user_model().objects.create(username='test_user2', 
                     password='test_pw')
        self.form = create(Post, {'user': self.user1, 'title': 'test_title'})
        self.client = Client()

        # Group setup
        group_name = "post admin"
        self.group = Group(name=group_name)
        self.group.save()

    def test_admin_can_delete(self):
        self.user2.groups.add(self.group)
        self.user2.save()
        self.client.login(username='test_user2', password='test_pw')

        response = self.client.post(reverse('posts:delete', kwargs={'pk': self.form.pk}))
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse('posts:list'))
```

still getting an error

```
Failure
Expected :'/accounts/login/?next=%2Fpost%2Fdelete%2F2143257160%2F'
Actual   :'/post/list/'
```